# Connect HDMI or Displayport to PC and display output with window (Windows 7, Mac Mini)

Tags: windows, mac, display, virtual-machine, vnc

To clarify, What I want to be able to do is the following:

I have 3 monitors and have all of them connected to my windows machine. The specs are not important as i suspect I will need new hardware for this anyway.

I want to get the output of my mac mini (either HDMI or Displayport), connect it to the windows machine and then display that input as a window on the desktop. This way I can just view the mac mini when I need to without changing the input source on my monitor. Kind of like a virtual PC but with physical hardware.

Also, I have a gigabyte switch that both the mac and windows machine are connected to if there is a way to do this over the network. I would need to be able to log into the mac through windows though.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Turn on screen sharing on your mini, and put in a password. Use a VNC client (UltraVNC) and whenever you want to do anything with your mini, just VNC into it.